# CQRS where to store statistics that are used by other BC's

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs

In our current application the user needs to be able to see certain statistics in his account. This data comes from different bounded contexts in the form of events. They typically consist of counters, like total distance tracked. Some user-bound stats are used for reports and charts as well. My question is where to store the user-bound stats. Like, are they part of the domain model (User aggregate)? Or are they just a materialised view eventually updated on multiple places?

So to visualize, using materialized views:

```
                                        /-> [User View updater]
[BC1] --> SomeInterestingToCountEvent1 <
                                        \-> [Report View updater]

                                        /-> [User View updater]
[BC2] --> SomeInterestingToCountEvent2 <
                                        \-> [Report View updater]
```

Or by having f.e. a Stats value object in user:

```
[BC1] --> SomeInterestingToCountEvent1 ---> [User Saga: update Stats]
[BC2] --> SomeInterestingToCountEvent2 ---> [User Saga: update Stats]

                                        /-> [User View updater]
[User BC] --> UserStatsUpdatedEvent    <
                                        \-> [Report View updater]
```

Answer (score 2):

> In our current application the user needs to be able to see certain statistics in his account. This data comes from different bounded contexts in the form of events.

So you may want to be thinking in terms of composite UIs

- Udi Dahan: [UI Composition Techniques for Correct Service Boundaries](http://udidahan.com/2012/06/23/ui-composition-techniques-for-correct-service-boundaries/)
- Jimmy Bogard: [Composite UIs for Microservices - A Primer](https://jimmybogard.com/composite-uis-for-microservices-a-primer/)

> My question is where to store the user-bound stats. Like, are they part of the domain model (User aggregate)? Or are they just a materialised view eventually updated on multiple places?

You probably want to be thinking of them as one or more materialized views.

Comment: Thanks! Well my problem is a bit more complicated. I can't split the UI as the counters are used to order objects in a list.

Comment: See my Edit in OP

Answer (score 1):

Materialised views generated and updated by listeners attached to any relevant event.

Comment: But isn't it easier since there are _multiple_ stats view (charts, totals) based on the same facts from other BC's to let a saga update the stats for a user? This ultimately results in a `UserStatsUpdatedEvent`, so multiple views can be based on those events and query the User Service (which is by then up to date with the new counters).

Comment: You certainly may, but if you use an event:

 - The saga is unaware of the stats, so changes in the stats requirements won't affect the design of the saga
 - If the event is sent in a queue, you can have handlers on separate nodes to update the stats - that would be far more efficient.

Comment: I think another argument against using saga would be that it will result in UserStatsUpdated events whenever a stat value is changed. This will implicitly increase the transaction footprint for User.

Comment: The only caveat I would like to add is - you need to be very careful about event sequencing and duplicates, particularly if you use an event bus that does not guarantee single delivery.